# go multiple-value in single-value context

Tags: go

I have a function returning 2 values: `string` and `[]string`

```
func executeCmd(command, port string, hostname string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (target string, splitOut []string) {

...
  return hostname, strings.Split(stdoutBuf.String(), " ")
}
```

This function is passed down to a go routine channel `ch`

```
  ch <- executeCmd(cmd, port, hostname, config)
```

I understand that when you want assign 2 or more values to a single variable, you need to create a `structure` and in case of go routine, use the structure to `make` a `channel`

```
    type results struct {
        target string
        output []string
    }
  ch := make(chan results, 10)
```

Being a beginner in GO, I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have seen other people having similar issue as mine but unfortunately the answers provided did not make sense to me

Comment: That's not a «function passed down to a … channel», that's whatever the call to that function is sent into that channel. But more importantly, your question is missing a crucial point: what do you want to _achieve._ Do you actually want to send all the values a call to `executeCmd` returns via a channel, or just one of the values it returns?

Comment: Your function returns two  values but you're using it as if it returns one value.

Comment: In that case your function must also return a results struct.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to catch the returned values into 2 different variables and I read that the best way to do it is using the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel can only take one variable so you are right that you need to define a structure to hold you results, however, you are not actually using this to pass into your channel.  You have two options, either modify `executeCmd` to return a `results`:

```
func executeCmd(command, port string, hostname string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) results {

...
  return results{
    target: hostname, 
    output: strings.Split(stdoutBuf.String(), " "),
  }
}

ch <- executeCmd(cmd, port, hostname, config)
```

Or leave `executeCmd` as it is and put the values returned into a struct after calling it:

```
func executeCmd(command, port string, hostname string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (target string, splitOut []string) {

...
  return hostname, strings.Split(stdoutBuf.String(), " ")
}

hostname, output := executeCmd(cmd, port, hostname, config)
result := results{
  target: hostname, 
  output: strings.Split(stdoutBuf.String(), " "),
}
ch <- result
```